# Setting $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ when integrating $x^2\ln x$ by parts

Tags: calculus, integration

I am a bit confused by this simple integral.

$\int{x^2\ln(x)}\,dx$

Integrating by parts by the formula $$\int{f(x)g'(x)}\,dx=f(x)g(x)-\int{f'(x)g(x)}\,dx$$ and setting $f(x)=x^2$ and $g'(x)=\ln(x)$ I get: $$x^2/x - \int2x/x\,dx = x-2x + C$$

I don't think this is correct but I can't figure out where I've gone wrong. When I ask an online integral calculator to do it it sets $f(x)=\ln(x)$ and $g'(x)=x^2$ and gets a completely different result, namely $\frac{x^3(3\ln(x)-1)}{9}+C$. I understand how the calculator arrives at this result but I can't figure out why I was wrong to set $f(x)$ and $g'(x)$ the way I did.

Comment: It seems that you are differentiating $g'$ to get $g$ whereas you should instead take an antiderivative.

Comment: If you let $g'(x)=\ln x$, then you need to solve $g(x)$, your work shows $g(x)=1/x$ and this is incorrect.

Comment: And the standard way to antidifferentiate $\log x$ is to use integration by parts, being sure to differentiate $\log x$, not antidifferentiate it.

Comment: You're right. Thank you for pointing out the mistake and for taking the time to answer my noob question. Of course $\int ln(x)\,dx$ does not equal $1/x$.  It's the other way around!

Comment: You are mixing $g(x)$ and $g''(x)$. If you set $g'(x)=\ln x$, then $g(x)=x\ln x-x+C$. You could integrate $\ln x$ by substituting $u=\ln x$.

Answer (score 3):

You must take $f(x) = \ln x$ and $g'(x) = x^2$, such that
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
\displaystyle \int x^2\ln x \,\mathrm{d}x 
   &=& \displaystyle
   \frac{1}{3}x^3\ln x - \int \frac{1}{3}x^3 \cdot \frac{1}{x} \,\mathrm{d}x \\
   &=& \displaystyle
   \frac{1}{3}x^3\ln x - \frac{1}{3}\int x^2\,\mathrm{d}x \\
   &=& \displaystyle
   \frac{1}{3}x^3\ln x - \frac{1}{9}x^3 \\
   &=& \displaystyle
   \frac{1}{3}x^3\left(\ln x - \frac{1}{3}\right)
\end{array} 
$$
letting aside the additive constant.